# What's bigger than a long double?

Tags: c, double, long-double, variable-types

So I'm trying to find the result of `1.25 ÷ (2 ✕ 10^-12)`.
I first tried doing it with python, but the result was too big it returned a negative number.
So I tried doing it in C, using a `long double`, but it's still not enough.

PS. I'm using GCC v9.2.1 on Linux Ubuntu

Comment: 6.25 x 10^11 doesn't seem that big, and can be represented exactly in a `double`.

Comment: Please show [mcve].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`long long` won't go bigger than a `long double`, but for your calculation, it's fine:

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main(){
    long long a = 1.25 / 2e-12;
    printf("%lld\n", a);
}
```

This prints `625000000000` for me.

Comment: Why doesn't it give the same with result when I use `^`?

Comment: @VirtualCode that's because the `^` operator isn't for exponentiation, but [bitwise XOR](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bitwise-operators-in-c-cpp/). `10 ^ 12` is `6`, because their bit pattern are `1010` respectively `1100`, so xor'd they are `0110`, which is the bit pattern for `6`.

Comment: `2 ✕ 10^-12 = 2e-12`, not `2 * 10e-12`. And the expression is done in double precision. To do in `long double` use `1.25L/2e-12L`

Comment: This is not a correct method. `2e-12` or `2e-12l` may round up when converted from decimal to the internal floating-point format, the division may round down, and then the result will not be `625000000000`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't see anything wrong with python:

```
>>> 1.25 / (2 * 10**-12)
625000000000.0
```

Comment: Why do I get `-0.0390625` when I replace `**` with `^` though?

Comment: use 2e-12 instead of `2 * 10**-12`

Comment: @VirtualCode because `^` is XOR operation ?

Comment: @lenik Yeah thanks, @Blaze told me above. But don't some languages have `^` as an exponentiation operator, though?

Comment: @VirtualCode I've never heard of any language using `÷` and `✕` =)

Comment: @lenik Take a look at APL.